# gwt mvp custom settings location

Tags: gwt, mvp

where is the best place for hold custom settings on GWT MVP project (eg: loged user, max amounts, min price or similars), y doubt if put them in gwt.xml config file, but I not understand how acces these XML defined tags (it's posible?), perhaps in appController class or others, which is the best place?, other options?, any suggestion is welcome.

thanks in advanced!!

Comment: I'm interested in this. Since in the example of the docs, activities are disposable and communicate through events, the only place to hold "global variables" seem to be the appcontroller or the clientfactory. Or should global data be requested with an event?

Comment: exact, this is my problem, it's the appcontroller the best place? get settings values throw the event bus not seem ideal, perhaps a custom xml file, I put them in any place but what its the "right" location on MVP pattern

Answer (score 2):

I tend to put them in a client context static class.  This way they are easily accessible from anywhere in your application and you can initialize them (where needed) on application startup or user login.